# Ionic 3 - Multiple apps under one project using different configurations

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I’m using Ionic 3, Angular 5.

I’d like to define multiple apps under one project. This is something that can be done in Angular, see https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/ 1 for example. Therefore, I expect this option to be available also in Ionic 3, yet I didn’t find a way to do it nor a source to demonstrate how to do it.

In other words:

Under different apps, I’d like to load different components for the same pages.

For example, saying I have a “LoginPage” that I’d like it to use a certain login component. This component should be “smsAuthComponent” for one app, and “credComponent” for another. I was told it is achievable by defining those different components (or the ones that import them) in a config file. Saying, changing configurations in one of the files of a single project (manifest.json [project/src/manifest.json], config.xml, ionic.config.js, or other file) that makes import of different components by different apps.

I case it's not clear enough: Having 2 different apps under 1 project, varying in their components - depending on project configurations.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this purpose?